# Sitecore Page Preview not working with multi site setup

Tags: sitecore, preview, presentation

I have a Sitecore project with multiple websites where the Preview option is not working like expected. When i'm on an item with a presentation and click on Preview in the presentation tab i get the following error:

The requested document was not found ->

```
Requested URL: /sitecore/content/<WebnameXXX>/home 
User Name: default\Anonymous 
Site Name: website 
If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an appropriate prefix    has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in the web.config.
```

What can I do to solve this issue?
I'm currently using 2 website nodes in the web.config file.

Web.config site nodes:

```xml
<site name="ggxxx_exxx1" hostName="ggxxx1.exxx.nl" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/gxxx1_nl" language="nl-NL" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="false" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableAnalytics="true" enableDebugger="false" disableClientData="false" />

<site name="ggxxx_exxx2" hostName="ggxxx2.exxx.nl" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/ggxxx2_nl" language="nl-NL" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="false" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableAnalytics="true" enableDebugger="false" disableClientData="false" />
```

Comment: Can you paste your web config, the bit that does the sites section. Is this standard Sitecore 6 or foundry??

Comment: This is Sitecore.NET 6.2.0 (rev. 100507)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your site definition is slightly off

/sitecore/content   --//---  home

(double slash)

Comment: Further to what Mark said, your `rootPath` and `startItem` attributes of the `site` definition (in `web.config`) should start but not end with a forward slash: `rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home"`

Comment: Double slash, i don't know how it came there? could you please show me how this is implemented in my web.config nodes that I pasted in my edit of the question?